# How do you create a doubly nested model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a double nested resource comments belongs to answer, answer belongs to question. I'm trying to create a comment with

```
def create
    @answer = Answer.find(params[:answer_id])
    @comment = @answer.comments.create(params[:comment])
    redirect_to question_path(@question)
end
```

From the form like this:

```
form_for([@answer, @answer.comments.build])
```

However, I'm getting an `undefined method error for render @answer.comments`. Is my create action wrong?

EDIT: I have the associations such as, answer has_many comments, and comment belongs_to answer and the nested routing file for resources..

Comment: Do you have `has_many :comments` association defined in `Answer` model?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to refactor so you're not doing the logic of building the comments in the view.

Build the comment in the `controller#new` action for the form, then

```
form_for [@answer, @comment]
```

Comment: what do you mean by not build comment in the view? I thought I've built a comment in the controller as an instance variable and in the form, I use answers.build.comment to ensure the comments are linked with the answer? that's what I've gotten from the rails tutorial but I'm new so I might've misunderstood it!

Answer (score 0):

First thing first.
In order to use @answer.comments you need to have

```
has_many :comments
```

in your answer.rb (model)

Comment: 2nd thing, you are building a form_for an object and a method... Should be 2 objects.